# Why is elm so picky about whitespace but only in certain cases?

Tags: elm

Why does this code fail

```
type SectionedItems s i = SectionedItems{
  section : s,
  items : List i,
  subsections: List (SectionedItems s i)
}

si1 : SectionedItems String String
si1 = SectionedItems{
  section  =  "",
  items = [
    "1",
    "2"
  ],
  subsections = [

  ]
}
```

and this code succeeds

```
type SectionedItems s i = SectionedItems{
  section : s,
  items : List i,
  subsections: List (SectionedItems s i)
}

si1 : SectionedItems String String
si1 = SectionedItems{
  section  =  "",
  items = [
    "1",
    "2"
  ],
  subsections = [

  ]
                    }
```

Why does elm fail for the first code? I know it is failing due to whitespace but why? Why do the `{` and `}` have to be aligned when creating an instance but not when declaring the type?

Comment: I would recommend using `elm-format` to eliminate the problem of formatting once and for all.

Comment: I would recommend reporting this issue to the [elm mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/elm-discuss). IMHO it is better to fix the problem at the source, and use `elm-format` only as a tool to only tidy code.

Comment: I agree the root problem should be made an issue with elm-compiler, but I also agree that elm-format will keep you from wasting your time on things like this.

Comment: It's not an issue with the compiler. But yes, definitely use `elm-format`. It'll save you time & trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that those brackets have to be lined up, it's that you can't put the closing bracket at the start of the line.

For example, this compiles:

```
si1 : SectionedItems String String
si1 = SectionedItems{
  section  =  "",
  items = [
    "1",
    "2"
  ],
  subsections = [

  ]
 }
```

Just putting in one extra space before the closing bracket is enough.

Why? Because the "children" of `si1` must have greater indentation than `si1` itself. If they don't, Elm thinks you're trying to start a new definition, and `}` isn't a valid way to start a definition.

Comment: Why does elm not error in the declaration of SectionedItems?